Ubuntu Budgie dark theme not applying correctly
I am relatively new to using Linux as my Desktop OS.
I have been using Ubuntu Budgie for a while now. I really love it, feels great to use.
Unfortunately I am having some issues with inconsistent themes.
I have installed Budgie a while back on my Laptop and just recently also on my main Desktop and both have the same issue.
I have applied some of the preinstalled themes and also the Orchis theme (amazing theme btw) but the majority of apps are not using a dark theme. Also Apps that use "System Theme" all default to light mode. So somehow the system isn't actually dark mode somehow.
I have set the styling preference in the Budgie Desktop settings to prefer dark, the themes I have tried were all dark.
After trying to research I found some stuff about connecting themes for snap apps. Tried that and it worked for 1 snap app, but the majority of snap apps and most non snap apps still don't use the dark theme.
It is not really a dealbreaker but it is really annoying, especially in apps that I use a lot but that don't their own dark mode setting.
Pretty much all the research I did lead to nothing, so I resort to posting here.
If you need any additional information let me know and I will to provide it.
